# Datepart error: Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_part("unknown", integer) does not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, datepart

I am trying to join two tables on this statement and receiving an error. Essentially, I want to join the date_dim_id, which is the date for two tables however, in table E the dates are one day behind, so I'm adding one day unless it is a Friday, where I am adding 3 days to join that date to the next business day, which is monday. Why is my case when not working?

```
ON a.date_dim_id = (CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday ,e.date_dim_id) = 5 THEN e.date_dim_id + 3 ELSE e.date_dim_id + 1 END)
```

Comment: Looks like PostrgeSQL,  `date_part('dow' ..` then

Comment: Is there a way to find the weekday of a date variable as opposed to a single date? The formula you sent works for a given day, but when I plug in the column e.date_dim_id, it doesnt work.

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.